# Как читать данные из текстового файла на русском?

Tags: c, windows, кодировка, cmd, unicode

Не получается считать русские буквы из файла (и вывести соответственно) из файла с форматом `.txt`. `Setlocale` и `SetConsoleCP` не помогают.

Comment: Файл в какой кодировке?

Comment: Кодировкаа UF-8

Comment: Куда выводишь? Если в `cmd.exe`, то попробуй `system("chcp 65001");`, либо смени кодировку текстового файла на `CP866`. Под виндой могу подсказать только Sublime для этого.

Comment: Но наверно Notepad++ тоже может.

Comment: Или можешь заюзать это =) https://github.com/pffang/libiconv-for-Windows

Comment: Если нужно на консоль выводить текст обязательно в кодировке UTF8, то первое, что приходит на ум - конвертировать UTF8 в UNICODE, а затем вызвать WideCharToMultiByte() для конвертирования в ANSI. Для работы с UTF8 есть открытые библиотеки, например: https://sourceforge.net/projects/utfcpp/

Comment: SetConsoleOutputCP?